# Вызов функции в Pandas

Tags: python, функции, pandas, dataframe

Есть некий датафрейм:

```
var1    var2
Fger    EEE
ffs     ss
DEE     aq#
```

Нужно провести некие преобразования, делаю это в функции:

```
def Func(df):
    df['var1']=df['var1'].str.lower()
    df['var2']=df['var2'].str.lower()
    df = df[df['var2']!='eee']
```

На выходе получаю:

```
    var1    var2
0   fger    eee
1   ffs     ss
2   dee     aq#
```

То есть последняя строка не сработала, почему такое может быть? И когда пытаюсь импортировать данную функцию, то выдает ошибку `name 'df' is not defined`

Comment: df = df[~df['var2']=='eee']

Comment: В таком случае выдает `bad operand type for unary ~: 'str'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df[df['var2']!='eee']` вернёт **новый** DataFrame объект, который удалится после вызова функции.

Демонстрация:

```
def Func(df):
    df['var1']=df['var1'].str.lower()
    df['var2']=df['var2'].str.lower()
    print("id(df) before : ", id(df))
    df = df[df['var2']!='eee']
    print("id(df) after  : ", id(df))
```

---

```
In [44]: id(df)
Out[44]: 2344845817448

In [45]: Func(df)
id(df) before :  2344845817448
id(df) after  :  2344850234840
```

---

Гораздо более правильно писать такие функции, которые возвращают результат своей работы при помощи оператора `return`:

```
def fun(df):
    df.loc[:, ["var1", "var2"]] = df[["var1", "var2"]].apply(lambda x: x.str.lower())
    df = df.query("var2 != 'eee'")
    return df
```

---

```
In [54]: df
Out[54]:
   var1 var2
0  Fger  EEE
1   ffs   ss
2   DEE  aq#

In [55]: df = fun(df)

In [56]: df
Out[56]:
  var1 var2
1  ffs   ss
2  dee  aq#
```

Comment: Я наверное не до конца вас понял, но в решении то это как поможет?

Comment: На выходе у меня только две строки остаться должно

Comment: @Max52, `"но в решении то это как поможет?"` - по-моему, важнее понять почему ваш код работает неправильно, чем получить готовое решение. Кстати, решение я добавил в ответ...

Comment: Хорошо, для пары функций это сработает, но если у меня 20 преобразований разных, которые я хочу в одну функцию запихнуть, то каждый раз придется такие конструкции прописывать?

Comment: @Max52, можете пояснить в чем вы видите преимущество вашего подхода? Я пока вижу только источник проблем... PS `"придется такие конструкции прописывать"` - какие конструкции вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Да я не про мой метод говорю, просто без функции это три команды, которые в целом норм отработают. А таких команд у меня около 30 , которые разные преобразования делают в DF.  Я просто хотел узнать, можно ли в функцию все это разом записать (или каким то иным образом сделать), чтобы все эти преобразования выполнялись 1 строчкой кода. Возможно лучше делать не через функцию, но я не знаю как. Подскажете?

Comment: @Max52, я, по-моему, именно это и показал - просто добавляете в ту же функцию __все__ преобразования и возвращаете в конце функции результат...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100895/discussion-between-max52-and-maxu).